# How to order table with two different columns having different data types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Tried to using this query:

```
SELECT clientId,
   CountryCode
FROM client
ORDER BY 
CASE 
WHEN CountryCode IS NULL
THEN clientId
ELSE CountryCode
END
```

But got error message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   
> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

The table structure is:

```
ClientId    numeric(10,0)
CountryCode char(3)
```

Comment: Do you want all records with a CountryCode to come first?  What's the data look like?

Comment: Please give example expected output. Right now it looks like you are trying to accomplish something that makes no sense, since numbers will sort above alpha country codes.

Comment: Does `ORDER BY CountryCode, clientID` not suffice?

Answer (score 8):

[This SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598c6/1) yields the error you described.

You need a different expression for each data type, or you need to make the lower-precedence data type (string) be compatible with the higher one (int) - usually by converting the int to a string.

Your requirements aren't clear, but the easier way is simply to order by one then the other. For example:

```
SELECT clientId, CountryCode
FROM dbo.client
ORDER BY CountryCode, clientId;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0d4e/1)

You can also introduce conditionals, but they don't seem to be required.

```
SELECT clientId,
   CountryCode
FROM dbo.client
ORDER BY CountryCode, CASE 
WHEN CountryCode IS NULL
THEN clientId END;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598c6/4)

...or this one, which orders in a slightly different way...

```
SELECT clientId,
   CountryCode
FROM dbo.client
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN CountryCode IS NULL
THEN clientId END, CountryCode;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598c6/3)

Again, your requirements are unclear - both of those may not produce the results you want. We can write the code you need if you show exactly what output you expect.

Answer (score -2):

> > The error SQL server defines from your query that: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> >     Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
> >     It clearly says cannot convert your varchar column ( CountryCode ) to numeric

```
SELECT clientId, CountryCode FROM client 
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN CountryCode IS NULL THEN clientId 
    ELSE CountryCode 
END
```

Modify your query with this. Works fine.

```
SELECT clientId, CountryCode FROM client 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN clientId IS NULL THEN CountryCode 
  ELSE CountryCode 
END
```

or you can use

```
SELECT clientId, CountryCode
FROM client
ORDER BY  
   CASE 
      WHEN CountryCode IS NULL 
         THEN Right(100000000000 + clientId, 10)
      ELSE CountryCode 
 END
```

Comment: Both cases are ordering by `CountryCode`

Comment: 7 AFG       
2 AUS       
1 IND       
3 NAM       
6 PAK       
5 RUS       
4 SAM

Comment: @mbeckish : pls see the output

Comment: @Kaf beat you to your second suggestion.